# scp on WebClient class in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, scp

I have a project already written using .Net's WebClient class.  It works great for FTP and WebDAV resources, but how can I get it to work with SCP or SFTP?

Answer (score 1):

The .Net framework contains no built-in SCP support;  try [SharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx).

The [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) class supports FTPES by setting the [EnableSsl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.enablessl.aspx) property, but WebClient doesn't expose it, so you'll have to use FtpWebRequest directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can make WebClient work with FTP/SSL (but not SFTP) by registering your own prefix:

```
private void RegisterFtps()
{
    WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("ftps", new FtpsWebRequestCreator());
}

private sealed class FtpsWebRequestCreator : IWebRequestCreate
{
    public WebRequest Create(Uri uri)
    {
        FtpWebRequest webRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri.AbsoluteUri.Remove(3, 1)); // Removes the "s" in "ftps://".
        webRequest.EnableSsl = true;
        return webRequest;
    }
}
```

Once you do this, you can use WebRequest almost like normal, except that your URIs start with "ftps://" instead of "ftp://". The one caveat is that you have to specify the method, since there won't be a default one. E.g.

```
// Note here that the second parameter can't be null.
webClient.UploadFileAsync(uploadUri, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, fileName, state);
```